# How to open new app with arguments from swift app using terminal command

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, command

Hello I want to open new app with arguments using terminal command with in swift code of my application MacOS

I have terminal command
`open -n /Applications/test.app -- args arg1`
this work fine when I run it in terminal

but when I am trying to run it using swift code

```
 static func shellCommand () {
        
        let task = Process()

        task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"

        let args:[String] = ["-c","open -n /Applications/test.app","--args aaaa"]

        task.arguments = args
        
        let pipe = Pipe()
        let errorPipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = errorPipe
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let errorData = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let error = String(decoding: errorData, as: UTF8.self)

        print("out put from shell command \(output) error \(error)")
    }
```

It doesn't work I also tried
`let args:[String] = ["-c","open -n /Applications/test.app --args arg1"]`

Thank you for any kind of hint or help

Comment: Why you tag thsi _bash_, if you then use zsh to launch the app? Also, _open_ is an external command on the Mac (executable file) and I don't see why you want to use a shell at all for executing this.

Comment: Hi @user1934428  sorry for the tag, but I think for this specific command the result is the same when I use bash or zsh on ```open -n /Applications/test.app -- args arg1```. 
I need to open the same app with new arguments

Comment: Why do you use a shell? You are not doing anything fancy which would need a shell?

Comment: I've never used Swift, but I would to it along [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-an-external-program-using-process). In your case, the program to run is _open_, and you need to pass the arguments as an array with 4 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that instead of this

```swift
let args = ["-c","open -n /Applications/test.app","--args aaaa"]
```

it should be this

```swift
let args = ["-c", "open", "-n", "/Applications/test.app", "--args", "aaaa"]
```

Also, you don't really need to go through zsh.  You could just call `open` directly.

```swift
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/open"
let args = ["-n", "/Applications/test.app", "--args", "aaaa"]
```